# Request.Querystring is empty

Tags: asp.net, iis

Strange one this..I'm looking for areas to investigate as much as an actual solution, but this is the issue:
In my asp.net webform page I am testing for a querystring which then applies some logic, however, the querystring appears to be stripped from the Url.
If I pass this

```
..blah.aspx?blah=123
```

then I can see the querystring in the Request.RawUrl no problem, but when I pass my proper querystring

```
..blah.aspx?Id=123
```

the querystring is empty. There is no request filtering on IIS either at the site or application level. Where else might this be stripped? Two hours of head scratching and counting....

Update:

There is no redirect, the logic is in the blah.aspx Pre Init event:

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(RequestLEID) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(RequestLEExternalReference))
        DisableNavigationContextCheck = true;

    base.OnPreInit(e);
}
```

Breaking on this event, I am testing the Request.RawUrl property in the immediate window

Comment: Can you please post code block where you're passing & redirecting to that url, thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

If you're using sharepoint (eg. a sharepoint control) with your solution, then ID is a reserved keyword.

Comment: I'm not using a sharepoint control and the querystring isn't actually ID (that's just an e.g. the actual querystring is "LEExternalReference"

Answer (score 0):

Nasty. Elsewhere in our code we have a navigation module. This had been updated to use RedirectPermanent which in the case of a url with a repeated querystring pattern (note, not the parameter itself) does not send the querystring with the Request object.

RedirectPermanent is a new method in asp.net 4.0 and certainly not something that we should be using here.

Answer (score 0):

are you pulling the value(s) out of the request?

```
var RequestLEExternalReference = Request.QueryString["LEExternalReference"];
```